# In SQL Server, can we set if it rounds or truncates by default?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I have a large number of inserts and updates coded in my program that involves money, and I cam across a serious rounding bug.  The majority of the time, I want to truncate the values, instead of the SQL Server default of rounding.

Rather than changing all my existing code, is there a way I can set this at a column level? Table level? Server level?

Edit: Sorry, the column type is a decimal(10, 2). Example: I want to enter 100.555 and either make it save as 100.55 or 100.56, as it currently rounds.

Comment: What is the column data type?

Comment: Sorry, decimal(10,2)

Comment: Can you give an example and the expected output?

Comment: edited, currently rounds, want to truncate in certain situations

Comment: Do you have a stored procedure that loads data into this column? If so, why not use **LEFT** function to truncate values as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options, other than fixing your code, or calling `SET ARITH_ABORT ON` for your batch.

Even if you do call `SET ARIGHT_ABORT ON`, it will only raise an error in cases of overflow, and will not complain about loss of precision/scale (such as when the significant digits are 0). The default behavior is to round.

[decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)